# Cannot add new data from JSON to adapter of Listview in Android

Tags: android, listview, android-volley

I am absolute beginner to Android. I am learning how to use volley and bind data to listview that come from response of volley request.When I make get request and retrieve response and convert it to model object. It all working fine. But when I bind it to Listview. It is throwing error. What is wrong with my code? Is this correct way to do like this?

My activity class

```
public class VolleyActivity extends Activity{
    private int lastSawFirstListItem;
    private int itemLoadedOn;
    private ArrayAdapter adapter;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.volley_main);

        Button getBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_get_request);
        getBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            }
        });

        ListView listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.volleyListView);
        adapter = new CustomAdapter(this,new Entity[0]);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        String url = "http://api.androidhive.info/feed/feed.json";

        JsonObjectRequest jsonRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject jsonObject) {
                List<Entity> items = new ArrayList<Entity>();
                try{
                    JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("feed");
                    for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++)
                    {
                        JSONObject item = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        Entity en = new Entity();
                        en.setId(item.getInt("id"));
                        en.setName(item.getString("name"));
                        en.setUrl(item.getString("url"));
                        items.add(en);
                    }
                    adapter.addAll(items);
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Success",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                catch (JSONException e)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {

            }
        });

        Volley.newRequestQueue(getBaseContext()).add(jsonRequest);
  }
}
```

This is my custom adapter

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Entity> {
    private final Context context;
    private final Entity[] values;

    public CustomAdapter(Context context,Entity[] values)
    {
        super(context,-1,values);
        this.context = context;
        this.values = values;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position,View convertView,ViewGroup parent)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row,parent,false);
        TextView id_text = (TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.row_id);
        TextView name_text = (TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.row_name);
        TextView url_text = (TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.row_url);
        id_text.setText(values[position].getId());
        name_text.setText(values[position].getName());
        url_text.setText(values[position].getUrl());
        return rowView;
    }
}
```

Here is the logcat when I run the activity

```
01-22 04:45:56.298 1492-1492/? W/EGL_genymotion: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
    01-22 04:45:56.354 477-492/? I/ActivityManager: Displayed com.example.newfeeds.newfeeds/.VolleyActivity: +110ms
    01-22 04:45:57.070 1492-1492/? D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
    01-22 04:45:57.070 1492-1492/? W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xa6219908)
    01-22 04:45:57.074 1492-1492/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    01-22 04:45:57.074 1492-1492/? E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    01-22 04:45:57.074 1492-1492/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.AbstractList.add(AbstractList.java:404)
    01-22 04:45:57.074 1492-1492/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.AbstractList.add(AbstractList.java:425)
    01-22 04:45:57.074 1492-1492/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.AbstractCollection.addAll(AbstractCollection.java:76)
    01-22 04:45:57.074 1492-1492/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.addAll(ArrayAdapter.java:195)
    01-22 04:45:57.074 1492-1492/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.example.newfeeds.newfeeds.VolleyActivity$2.onResponse(VolleyActivity.java:66)
    01-22 04:45:57.074 1492-1492/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.example.newfeeds.newfeeds.VolleyActivity$2.onResponse(VolleyActivity.java:51)
    01-22 04:45:57.074 1492-1492/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonRequest.deliverResponse(JsonRequest.java:65)
    01-22 04:45:57.074 1492-1492/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:99)
    01-22 04:45:57.074 1492-1492/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
    01-22 04:45:57.074 1492-1492/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    01-22 04:45:57.074 1492-1492/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    01-22 04:45:57.074 1492-1492/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
    01-22 04:45:57.074 1492-1492/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    01-22 04:45:57.074 1492-1492/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    01-22 04:45:57.074 1492-1492/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
    01-22 04:45:57.074 1492-1492/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
    01-22 04:45:57.074 1492-1492/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    01-22 04:45:57.074 477-698/? W/ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity com.example.newfeeds.newfeeds/.VolleyActivity
    01-22 04:45:57.150 477-698/? D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 129K, 29% free 9794K/13620K, paused 10ms, total 10ms
    01-22 04:45:57.654 477-490/? W/ActivityManager: Activity pause timeout for ActivityRecord{533353cc u0 com.example.newfeeds.newfeeds/.VolleyActivity}
    01-22 04:46:07.154 477-490/? W/ActivityManager: Launch timeout has expired, giving up wake lock!
    01-22 04:46:07.654 477-490/? W/ActivityManager: Activity idle timeout for ActivityRecord{53441ff4 u0 com.example.newfeeds.newfeeds/.MainActivity}
    01-22 04:46:20.714 56-56/? D/Genyd: Received Set Clipboard
    01-22 04:46:20.714 56-56/? D/Genymotion: Received Set Clipboard
    01-22 04:47:00.034 477-480/? D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 1670K, 28% free 9848K/13620K, paused 1ms+2ms, total 25ms
    01-22 04:47:15.470 56-56/? D/Genyd: Received Set Clipboard
    01-22 04:47:15.470 56-56/? D/Genymotion: Received Set Clipboard
```

Is that a proper way of using volley with Listview and binding data? How can I fix this error?

Then I changed from Entity[] to `ArrayList<Entity>` in my custom adapter. It still throwing error.

My new custom adapter class with ArrayList

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Entity> {
    private final Context context;
    private final ArrayList<Entity> values;

    public CustomAdapter(Context context,ArrayList<Entity> values)
    {
        super(context,-1,values);
        this.context = context;
        this.values = values;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position,View convertView,ViewGroup parent)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row,parent,false);
        TextView id_text = (TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.row_id);
        TextView name_text = (TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.row_name);
        TextView url_text = (TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.row_url);
        id_text.setText(values.get(position).getId());
        name_text.setText(values.get(position).getName());
        url_text.setText(values.get(position).getUrl());
        return rowView;
    }
}
```

This is the logcat after I changed to ArrayList

```
01-22 05:09:54.770 1895-1895/? W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xa6219908)
    01-22 05:09:54.774 1895-1895/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    01-22 05:09:54.774 1895-1895/? E/AndroidRuntime: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x1
    01-22 05:09:54.774 1895-1895/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:230)
    01-22 05:09:54.774 1895-1895/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3769)
    01-22 05:09:54.774 1895-1895/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.example.newfeeds.newfeeds.CustomAdapter.getView(CustomAdapter.java:36)
    01-22 05:09:54.774 1895-1895/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2159)
    01-22 05:09:54.774 1895-1895/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1831)
    01-22 05:09:54.774 1895-1895/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:674)
    01-22 05:09:54.774 1895-1895/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:735)
    01-22 05:09:54.774 1895-1895/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1638)
    01-22 05:09:54.774 1895-1895/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:1994)
    01-22 05:09:54.774 1895-1895/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14008)
    01-22 05:09:54.774 1895-1895/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
    01-22 05:09:54.774 1895-1895/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1663)
    01-22 05:09:54.774 1895-1895/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1521)
    01-22 05:09:54.774 1895-1895/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
    01-22 05:09:54.774 1895-1895/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14008)
    01-22 05:09:54.774 1895-1895/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
    01-22 05:09:54.774 1895-1895/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
    01-22 05:09:54.774 1895-1895/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14008)
    01-22 05:09:54.774 1895-1895/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
    01-22 05:09:54.774 1895-1895/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1663)
    01-22 05:09:54.774 1895-1895/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1521)
    01-22 05:09:54.774 1895-1895/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
    01-22 05:09:54.774 1895-1895/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14008)
    01-22 05:09:54.774 1895-1895/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
    01-22 05:09:54.774 1895-1895/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
    01-22 05:09:54.774 1895-1895/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14008)
    01-22 05:09:54.774 1895-1895/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
    01-22 05:09:54.774 1895-1895/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:1892)
    01-22 05:09:54.774 1895-1895/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1711)
    01-22 05:09:54.774 1895-1895/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:989)
    01-22 05:09:54.774 1895-1895/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4351)
    01-22 05:09:54.774 1895-1895/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
    01-22 05:09:54.774 1895-1895/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
    01-22 05:09:54.774 1895-1895/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
    01-22 05:09:54.774 1895-1895/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
    01-22 05:09:54.774 1895-1895/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
    01-22 05:09:54.774 1895-1895/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    01-22 05:09:54.774 1895-1895/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    01-22 05:09:54.774 1895-1895/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
    01-22 05:09:54.774 1895-1895/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    01-22 05:09:54.774 1895-1895/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    01-22 05:09:54.774 1895-1895/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
    01-22 05:09:54.774 1895-1895/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
    01-22 05:09:54.774 1895-1895/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    01-22 05:09:54.778 477-489/? W/ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity com.example.newfeeds.newfeeds/.VolleyActivity
    01-22 05:09:54.894 477-489/? D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 179K, 33% free 9817K/14460K, paused 15ms, total 15ms
    01-22 05:09:55.398 477-490/? W/ActivityManager: Activity pause timeout for ActivityRecord{5334f1a0 u0 com.example.newfeeds.newfeeds/.VolleyActivity}
```

Comment: Can you post your CustomAdapter class too.

Comment: Yes, I just edited the question.

Comment: But when I remove this two lines //adapter.addAll(items);
                    //adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); , it is toasting success message.

Comment: Check my answer hope this will help you.

Comment: post your Entity class too.

Comment: public class Entity {
    private int Id;
    private String Name;
    private String Url;

    public void setId(int id)
    {
        this.Id = id;
    }

    public int getId()
    {
        return this.Id;
    }

    public void setName(String name)
    {
        this.Name = name;
    }

    public String getName()
    {
        return this.Name;
    }

    public void setUrl(String url)
    {
        this.Url = url;
    }

    public String getUrl()
    {
        return this.Url;
    }
}

Comment: @Waiyan, i have updated the answer kindly check that, code is also available here https://github.com/pankajnimgade/Tutorial/blob/master/app/src/main/java/listview/test/activities/ListVewTestThreeActivity.java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer by the combination of the answers of Pankaj Nimgade and Soham. First I convert the values of my custom adapter to ArrrayList instead of array. Then I retrieve the value of id that is integer like this in adapter.

```
String.valueOf(values.get(position).getId())
```

It does not even need adapter.notifyDataSetChanged().It worked. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1):

Ok if i understand right, you are using `Entity[] values` which is a normal array which you would have to define how big it can be when you initialize it.

the problem is that with this normal array is that It can not be expanded or shrunk on the go (what I mean is you can't reduce or add more items to it). so it's size remains same as it was initialized.

and in your activity what you providing is a `ArrayList` object which can have items added or removed on the go.

so this is the conflict you are facing here,

what you need to do is have a `ArrayList` instance in the `Customadapter`, something like this,

```
    private final Context context;
    private final ArrayList<Entity> values;

    public CustomAdapter(Context context,ArrayList<Entity> values;
    {
        super(context,-1,values);
        this.context = context;
        this.values = values;
    }
```

now you can assign values like this 
    ArrayList values = new ArrayList();
    CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(this, values );

after calling the network call add the items to the list like this

```
values.addAll(items);
```

and call this method `notifyDataSetChanged()` as you have the advantage of using observer pattern

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

you can also have a look at some of example on `listview` population using `JSON` on [github](https://github.com/pankajnimgade/Tutorial/blob/master/app/src/main/java/activities/list/first/CustomListViewActivity.java),

and you do have to think more like OOP, make a model class whose instance will save the data for you

```
public class Entity {

    private String id;
    private String name;
    private String url;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }
    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }
}
```

> Update,
>   as there is a lot of confusion, try this

```
public class ListVewTestThreeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ListView listView;
    private ArrayList<Entity> entities;
    private MyAdapter myAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_vew_test_three);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_custom_toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        initializeUI();
    }

    private void initializeUI() {
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListVewTestThreeActivity_listView);
        entities = new ArrayList<>();
        myAdapter = new MyAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.simple_list_item_1, entities);
        listView.setAdapter(myAdapter);

        new DownloadJSON().execute();
    }

    private class DownloadJSON extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        private ArrayList<Entity> tempEntities;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            tempEntities = new ArrayList<>();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

            try {

                URL url = new URL("http://api.androidhive.info/feed/feed.json");
                HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                httpURLConnection.connect();

                String result = IOUtils.toString(httpURLConnection.getInputStream());
                System.out.println("" + result);

                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);
                JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("feed");

                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                    Entity entity = new Entity();
                    entity.setId(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("id"));
                    entity.setName(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("name"));
                    entity.setUrl(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("image"));
                    System.out.println(""+entity.getName());
                    tempEntities.add(entity);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);

            if (tempEntities != null) {
                entities.addAll(tempEntities);
                System.out.println("Size: "+entities.size());
                myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

        }
    }


    private class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

        private ArrayList<Entity> a_productInfos;
        private Context a_context;
        private LayoutInflater a_layoutInflater;

        public MyAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<Entity> a_productInfos) {
            super(context, resource, a_productInfos);
            this.a_productInfos = a_productInfos;
            this.a_context = context;
            a_layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(this.a_context);
        }


        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View row = convertView;
            ViewHolder holder = null;
            if (row == null) {
                row = a_layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.single_item_listview_test_three, parent, false);
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                holder.id = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.ListVewTestThreeActivity_id_textView);
                holder.name = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.ListVewTestThreeActivity_name_textView);
                holder.url = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.ListVewTestThreeActivity_url_textView);
                row.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) row.getTag();
            }

            final Entity productInfo = a_productInfos.get(position);
            holder.id.setText("" + productInfo.getId());
            holder.name.setText("" + productInfo.getName());
            holder.url.setText("" + productInfo.getUrl());
            return row;
        }

        class ViewHolder {
            TextView id;
            TextView name;
            TextView url;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return super.getCount();
        }
    }

    public class Entity {

        private String id;
        private String name;
        private String url;

        public String getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(String id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public String getUrl() {
            return url;
        }

        public void setUrl(String url) {
            this.url = url;
        }
    }
}
```

> Output

[image]

Update

Comment: Yes I changed it. It still throwing error. I just edited the question.

Comment: @Waiyan, i have this working example of listview population, kindly check how the adapter is set https://github.com/pankajnimgade/Tutorial/blob/master/app/src/main/java/activities/list/first/CustomListViewActivity.java

Answer (score 0):

Please replace your code with below code and Let me know if this is helpful.

**VolleyActivity**

```
    public class VolleyActivity extends Activity{
    private int lastSawFirstListItem;
    private int itemLoadedOn;
    private ArrayAdapter adapter;
    private List<Entity> items;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.volley_main);

        Button getBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_get_request);
        getBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            }
        });
        items = new ArrayList<Entity>();
        ListView listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.volleyListView);
        adapter = new CustomAdapter(this, items);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        String url = "http://api.androidhive.info/feed/feed.json";

        JsonObjectRequest jsonRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject jsonObject) {
                List<Entity> items = new ArrayList<Entity>();
                try{
                    JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("feed");
                    for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++)
                    {
                        JSONObject item = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        Entity en = new Entity();
                        en.setId(item.getInt("id"));
                        en.setName(item.getString("name"));
                        en.setUrl(item.getString("url"));
                        items.add(en);
                    }
                    adapter.addAll(items);
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Success",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                catch (JSONException e)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {

            }
        });

        Volley.newRequestQueue(getBaseContext()).add(jsonRequest);
    }
}
```

**CustomAdapter**

```
    public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Entity> {
      private final Context context;
      private List<Entity> values;

      public CustomAdapter(Context context,List<Entity> values){
         super(context,-1,values);
         this.context = context;
         this.values = values;
      }

      @Override
      public View getView(int position,View convertView,ViewGroup parent)
      {
          LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
          View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row,parent,false);
          TextView id_text = (TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.row_id);
          TextView name_text = (TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.row_name);
          TextView url_text = (TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.row_url);
          id_text.setText(String.valueOf(values.get(position).getId()));
          name_text.setText(values.get(position).getName());
          url_text.setText(values.get(position).getUrl());
          return rowView;
      }
     }
```

Comment: I tried like that. Throwing error. U just edited the question.

Comment: Did you change values[position].getId() to values.get(position).getId() in CustomAdapter class?? @Waiyan

Comment: Yes I did absolutely

Comment: Replace id_text.setText(values.get(position).getId()); to id_text.setText(String.valueOf(values.get(position).getId())); I have Edited CustomAdapter class also. Please check. @Waiyan

Comment: Yes I just posted the answer now

Answer (score 0):

I think you are getting the error in the below line in your `adapter` class `id_text.setText(values[position].getId());` You have to change it to

```
id_text.setText(String.valueOf(values[position].getId()))
```

It's simple because you have to pass String in the `setText` method. Currently it's getting `int` value that's why it's going to find the resource from the [R](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.html).That's why it's throwing `Resources$NotFoundException` .

Hope it's clear to you.

Comment: I didn't see any changes in your class.Did you understand what I am trying to say

Comment: I posted adapter class in two versions

Comment: It does not work on array adapter. So I converted the values of custom adapter to arraylist and I tried like this. I tried like this on AarrayAdapter. String.valueOf(values.get(position).getId()) . It worked. It does not work with array adapter.